# MSMQ WMI Returning Queue Lengths of 0

Tags: wmi, msmq, windows-server-2012-r2, wmi-query

When trying to get the queue length of a MSMQ queue using WMI most queues return the length of 0.

I have tried to retrieve the lengths via the .NET System.Management class, Performance Monitor and via PowerShell (All run on the local server):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_msmq_MSMQQueue -Filter "Name LIKE '%QUEUENAME%'" | ft -AutoSize -property Name,MessagesInQueue,BytesInQueue;
```

I don't get any errors, all methods find the queue fine, they just return a queue length 0 every time.

I know there are messages in the queue as checking the queue via .NET System.Messaging and the GetAllMessages method returns the correct length of the queue, and drilling down to the queue in Computer Management also shows the correct length of the queue.

Some of the queues seem to work, and report the correct length from WMI, but I cannot see anything that differentiates them (They're all transactional, private, non-journalled queues, with no authentication)

We have A LOT of queues on the server ~2200 at the moment, because each hardware device that connects into our server has it's own queue. This has been running so far with no problems on our live environment, with our communications engine pulling messages off and putting messages on all queues with no issue.

Server has had a reboot since I've noticed this, and that has not solved the problem. The example queues I am looking at have the hardware device disconnected so the communication engine isn't consuming the messages from those queues.

Server is a m3.medium from Amazon AWS, Server 2012 R2.

I am stumped, I don't know what else to look at to try and work this out.

Comment: The queue length should be zero if the queue was empty at the time you started monitoring. So 5 messages could arrive later but you wouldn't know as the data structure didn't exist when the app first looked. The data structure only exists if the queue has >0 messages OR the hardware device has an active handle on the queue. Would that explain why you see some queues working?

Comment: If the problem is indeed the queues being empty initially then I have a blog post for that. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/09/26/monitoring-empty-queues-in-msmq.aspx

Comment: Hi John, unsure if this is too old for me to respond to. The messages queues definitely have messages in them as I have created messages for those queues in question, and verified it with a call to the GetAllMessages in .NET where it retrieves the messages I expect to see in there.

Comment: Maybe not enough memory for WMI to store the information? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/09/16/memory-and-handle-quotas-in-the-wmi-provider-service/

Comment: @Oliver: We experience the same problem. Did you solve it in the mean time?

Comment: Nope unfortunately we never resolved this issue. We're currently looking at swapping away from MSMQ because of this.

Comment: Have just noticed the comment from John above this - my apologies John I didn't see this earlier. The server has 8GB of ram assigned to it, and it sits at about 55% - so I wouldn't imagine it's memory related. Also never seen a "Out of Memory" error. It just returns 0.